# Difference between :self and ClassName when type hinting return type

Tags: php, return-type, type-hinting

In PHP, when I specify a return type for a method that is supposed to return an instance of the class, I can do so like this:

```
class Foo  {
    public function bar(): self  { ... }
}
```

or:

```
class Foo  {
    public function bar(): Foo  { ... }
}
```

both seem to produce the same results / behavior.

What's the difference?  Is one best practice over the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What's the difference?

There is no difference.
`self` is a keyword that refers to the class itself.

You can think of it as an alternative name of the class being defined,
thus in your example `self` is an alternative name of `Foo`.
In other words, you can use `self` to replace `Foo` wherever you want,
except right after the `class` keyword, of course.

Here is an example:

```
class Foo {
    const HELLO = 'Hello!';

    public function bar(): Foo {
        echo Foo::HELLO;
        return new Foo;
    }
}
```

Which is exactly the same as this:

```
class Foo {
    const HELLO = 'Hello!';

    public function bar(): self {
        echo self::HELLO;
        return new self;
    }
}
```

> Is one best practice over the other?

No.
Simply use whichever is most convenient or most useful to you.

I usually prefer to use `self` so that if I need to rename the class, I only need to rename it in one place (right after `class`).

Comment: Do you not agree with @tomiwahq answer then? They have outlined a very distinct difference

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference between the two.

However, if you want something similar but different, use `:static` (Requires PHP 8.0 and above).
The difference is that returning class name, as in this case `Foo` will return the particular class returned (not the child class) while returning `static` will return the class the object was instantiated from (even if it's a child of the class where the method was defined).

For instance,

```
class Foo
{
    public function bar(): static { ... }

    public function rab(): Foo { ... }
}

class BabyFoo extends Foo
{
}

$instance = new BabyFoo();
```

In the code snippet above,
`$instance->bar()` will return `BabyFoo`
while
`$instance->rab()` will return `Foo`

Comment: That is wrong. Both methods will return BabyFoo. @Rei answer is a correct one.

Comment: Good edit, not sure how you got 7 upvotes with a wrong answer but this is much better!

Comment: I was shocked too. I still wonder how I wrote that too. Thanks @DeveloperKid for pointing it out